# Django class based view instance variables

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

This a the class (in Django 1.7.4) I do not understand... in the `form_valid()` function:

```
class ImportCsv(FormView):
    template_name = "backend/import.html"
    form_class = UploadFileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("b_import_csv")
    csverrors = []

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(ImportCsv, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx.update({
                "csverrors" : self.csverrors,
            })
        return ctx

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.csverrors.append("Yeah")
        self.template_name+="yeah"
        return super(ImportCsv, self).form_valid(form)
```

This class just shows what I cannot understand: once the form is valid, `form_valid()` is called. There I change two things: `self.csverrors` and `self.template_name`.

Then I reload my page: the template name is still the original one, but csverrors remembers the "Yeah". I can submit the form again and again: csverrors keeps growing. The point is: I can change also `self.form_class` and `self.success_url`, but everything will be restored in the next connection. Why csverrors is still there?

I cannot see the differences between those two variables and why they act differently. I know the function `get_gemplate_names()` in this particular case, but this is a general question about instance variables.

The goal was just to put something in an instance variable and change `get_success_url()` accordingly to that variable. Problem: that variable will not go away.

Answer (score 4):

`csverrors` points to the single list regardless of the number of `ImportCsv` views.  This list is created at the time then you define `ImportCsv` class and never recreated again.

So you should create the new list in the `form_valid()`:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.csverrors = ["Yeah"]
    ...
```

Or create the new empty list in the `dispatch()` method:

```
class ImportCsv(FormView):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.csverrors = []
        return super(ImportCsv, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```